# Matrix Randomization

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, random

Is there a way to take a 20x20 array and replace 2 random parts of this array with a 2x2 matrix?

I've tried

`rvalues = ConstantArray[r, {20, 20}];`

to make the array, but dont know how to use `ReplacePart[rvalues, RandomInteger]`

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 6;
a = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
pos = RandomSample[1 ;; n, 2];
vals = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {2, 2}];
```

Now you can either perform the replacement with `ReplacePart`

```
anew = ReplacePart[a, Thread[Tuples[pos, 2] -> Flatten[vals]]];
anew // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

or in-place with `Part`

```
a[[pos, pos]] = vals;
a // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Comment: Might want to use `RandomSample[Range[n], 2]` instead, to avoid repeats.

Comment: @CarlWoll Good point!. Thanks.